# Aggregate time series from weeks to month

Tags: r, time-series, aggregate

Assume a timeseries ts with frequency(ts) = 52:

```
Time Series:
Start = c(2010, 34) 
End = c(2013, 25) 
Frequency = 52 
...
```

I want to aggregate ts such that frequency(ts) = 12.

If the new frequency divides the old one, one can use

```
aggregate(ts, nfrequency = k, FUN = sum)
```

But if old frequency mod new frequency > 0 it does not work:

```
> ts <- aggregate(ts, nfrequency = 12, FUN = sum)
Error in aggregate.ts(ts, nfrequency = 12, FUN = sum) : 
cannot change frequency from 52 to 12
```

I can a imagine to loop through the time series and decide for each value if to add it completely or a fraction of it, but I am surely not the first one with that requirement. So is there any predefined function doin that?

Answer (score 10):

Yes there are predefined function doing aggregation by month or more generally by any period of time.You can use `xts` package is very handy for time series manipulations.

For example , you can use `apply.monthly` :

```
library(xts)
ts.month <- apply.monthly(as.xts(ts),FUN=sum)
```

Comment: sorry, it is not working for me: 
a <- ts(1:10, start=c(1,6), end=c(2,5), frequency=10) 
     as.xts(a)
     Error in as.xts.ts(a) : could not convert index to appropriate type

Comment: it is due to the frequency. This works for example: `as.xts(ts(1:4,start=c(1,6), end=c(2,5), frequency=4))`. You should create a regular time series using xts constructor. see the xts help.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioend, if you do not mind loading another package, I recommend using the aggregate function in **zoo** or similar functions in **xts**. You will probably need these packages anyway, especially if you run into ragged timeseries data. Here are examples of aggregating to a monthly timeseries using **zoo** followed by **xts**:

**zoo:**

```
monthlyTS <- aggregate(dailyTS, as.yearmon, sum)
```

**xts:**

```
monthlyTS <- apply.monthly(xts(dailyTS), mean)
```

Pure syntactic sugar! What's really nice about **xts** is that you can aggregate by week. However, it's trivial to add new aggregation functions to the **zoo** function too.

Cheers,

Adam